# How to retract content after expiration date

Tags: plone

one of our customers is using in their site third party content that must be unavailable after one month because of license restrictions.

in this specific case expiring content will not help because the content is still available on the site and is viewable by anyone who already has its address.

we make a quick research and found an old tutorial by our friend Mikko Ohtamaa (who else?) about [Time based workflow transitions](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/time-based-workflow-transitions) and I'm currently checking if dependencies work on latest versions of Plone.

does anybody else has a different approach on how to retract content after expiration date or this is the best one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collective.autopublishing can publish / retract content based on effective/expiration date, or a custom date field. Using a cron or clockserver trigger to search for content to retract or publish.
See https://github.com/collective/collective.autopublishing

Comment: In our specific use case the owner of the rights only wanted the content not to be indexed by search engines outside of our customer site, so we ended up by adding a viewlet that inserts an HTML meta tag on specific items (the ones where the author is the owner of the rights), so I just ended up using `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`

Answer (score 4):

To me this is screaming for a contentrule (really like them) and [collective.contentrules.comingsoon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.contentrules.comingsoon) claims to be able to do what you want, since of version 1.1 passing the index-parameter is possible. Don't get distracted of the initial naming of the product. I haven't tested this but the authors are well known for good prods. For me for sure. And the latest release is quite fresh, which hints, it was used with newer Plone-versions.

Comment: The problem with content rules is that arriving to an expiration date does not fire any event and we will need to create some sort of complex solution to deal with this. I think the easiest way is just to create a cron job calling a browser view that will retract all content.

Comment: But did you have a look? The products combines a contentrule with a cron, which you can also configure via z3c.recipe.usercrontab.

Comment: In other words: The prod does exactly what you describe, the README even gives an example with the expiration-date.

Comment: hold, I haven't had time to test it as I'm working in other more urgent stuff now :-)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this and want to share? Refs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992592/control-access-on-future-content and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118425/plone-image-visibility-with-one-state-workflow

Comment: sorry, Ida, I have zillion of pending things and some stuff just keep piling; still on my todo list :-(