# Control access on future content

Tags: security, authorization, plone, access-control

this is mostly about public content timed on the future, but not only.

In a standard Plone site if you create a top-level content is not shown on the navigation (is still private), then you make it public (via workflow) and it shows up on the navigation, but later you time it in the future and again it disappears from the navigation.

Still, at that point, if an anonymous/logged-in user knows the URL they will be able to see the content.

In our case, a newspaper, we not only have that (content timed to the future) but we also have different roles of users which need or don't have to see that content (paid subscribers/premium users...).

Checking for `View` permission, i.e.

```py
security = getSecurityManager()
if security.checkPermission('View', obj):
   # user can see the object
```

is not enough.

Check for view permission and if the content is in the future, i.e.

```py
security = getSecurityManager()
if security.checkPermission('View', obj) and \
        not object.effective_date.isFuture():
   # user can see the object
```

again is not enough as some users do need to see future content (i.e. content editors) while normal users should not and on top of that premium users should do see them, so something like this would actually do:

```py
security = getSecurityManager()
if security.checkPermission('View', obj) and \
        (not object.effective_date.isFuture() or 
         security.checkPermission('Can see future content', obj):
   # user can see the object
```

But the question then is: as this has to be used throughout the website (lead pages, articles, cross-linking, navigation, searches...) it doesn't feel right and is quite tedious to have to repeat all this checks all over everywhere.

Is there any other approach on how to solve this?

Comment: Mind to give some feedback?

Comment: Refs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521111/how-to-retract-content-after-expiration-date and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118425/plone-image-visibility-with-one-state-workflow

Answer (score 4):

there is an addon product that does exactly what you need:

collective.wfeffectiverange

it works by adding a cron job that looks for not yet published (effective date in the future) or expired (expiration date reached) content and apply a workflow transition in this case.

see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.wfeffectiverange for more information

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @goodMan i'd aggree if the link has pointed to a blogpost explaining how to do a certain setup. but as this link pointed to an existing plone addon i personally think simply adding a link is enough in this case. even if the github repository would be moved, people can still search for the package name. anyway, i updated the answer and would be glad if you removed your downvote

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this add-on! Wasn't aware of it, yet. Looks promising for slightly more complex usecases, say the user needs to set the destination-wf-state also. Where when there's just one wanted destination-state, it would be defined without the need of an additional useraction, as in the c.comingsoon-answer above.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Create a contenttype per privilege-level you want to have ('premium', 'paid subscriber') and assign a dedicated workflow to each, holding at least the states 'editors-review' and 'premium-published', respectively 'editors-review' and 'paidsub-published', and wire the states to equivalent roles ('editors', premiumusers', 'paidsubscribers'), to grant the View-permissions, as intended.
Additionally it is recommandable to create a group for each role, wire them together, and assign the users to the groups, instead to roles.

2.) Use [collective.contentrules.comingsoon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.contentrules.comingsoon) to apply a contentrule which sets the state from 'editors-review' to 'premium-published', respectively 'editors-review', when the publishing-date is met (executed via a browserview, triggered of a cron).

3.) To overcome Plone's default setting, that items with a publish-date set in the future won't appear in navi-elements, you need to customize/override the refering templates. That'll include globalnav, navportlet, sitemap, folder_listing, etc.

Comment: 1) would not work, our target is to get everyone to see everything at some point, so we do need to keep a single content type and a single workflow

Comment: 3) that's not really a problem for us we nearly have no navigation elements

Comment: 1) Maybe I didn't get well the requirements of your description. The principle should be same, just let the cron switch the wf-state to published, then. The per contenttype suggestion was ment to represent the premium/paidsubscr-distinction.