# Plone image visibility with one state workflow

Tags: image, workflow, plone

I am using 'one state workflow' for image types in Plone, and it appears an anonymous user can still see an image even if it's 'publishing date' is set in the future...

Is 'publishing date' ignored in 'one state workflow' for images?

It also appears 'expiry date' is also ignored ie it appears when you dial up its url.

Note: I am accessing the image direct via it's URL eg my.site.com/assets/images/myexpiredimage

Perhaps these publish/expiry dates only useful for listings and collections etc, they dont control access and visibility?

Tried to find good Plone doco on this but couldn't... happy for a link to where this is explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these things do nothing about people who have the URL, ever, regardless of workflow. The best quote for this I could find in three minutes is [hidden in the user manual glossary](http://docs.plone.org/appendices/glossary.html#term-expiration-date).

Comment: Yes i looked for doco on this for about 5 minutes and didn't find it specified clearly anywhere at an author/user level. This query originated from an author so this piece of UI is not described properly in context (or in reference doco).

Comment: For example if you have an 'expired' image in a static text portlet, everyone can see it... even though the UI for 'expiry date' says "Expiration Date The date when the item expires. This will automatically make the item invisible for others at the given date." Not true.

Comment: @AaronWilliams How did this answer resolve your quest? If you don't want the image to be accessible after a given date, set the initial state to private, set the pub-date, let a cron publish the item (= switch wf-state to 'published') when the date is met, as described in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it might not have been clear my question was about Plone UI and was from a question from a content author and related to doco about this piece of UI which is confusing for authors... as soon as you talk cron-job that's a) not Plone and b) not something helpful to an author.

Comment: The feature is confusing because it doesn't regard the user's permissions, simply hides the items for *everyone* of the listings, if not in the given date-range. If one wants to regard that, there is no other way, than to use a periodically event-listener like cron is, because it depends on a date arriving, whereas the triggering event for the list-checks, is the user calling the template, no listening needed. It would be nice though actually, if Plone integrates a daily cron by default, that can be wired to executables via the UI.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the publication- or expiration-date merely means the item will not show up in listings (navi-elements, search results, folder-listings), and is not to be confused with workflow-states.

A better solution would be to change the wf-state, when a date is met via a cron, which can be done quite comfortably with [collective.contentrules.comingsoon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.contentrules.comingsoon).

Yet you need to rip out the default-behaviour of the concerned templates, I'm not sure, but maybe there is a proposal ("PLIP") already going on for this, if you find one, please  leave the link here.

Refs: [Control access on future content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992592/control-access-on-future-content/27001293#27001293) and [How to retract content after expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521111/how-to-retract-content-after-expiration-date)