# Installation of collective.autopublishing

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I want to use collective.autopublish to set outdated Plone pages to private.
The goal is to set Plone pages to private after the expiration date automatically. (similar to the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521111/how-to-retract-content-after-expiration-date))

I installed collective.autopublish and I can configure it in the web interface. It should use the collective.timedevents extension to get triggered. So I added that as well and tried to install it using the [readme](https://github.com/collective/collective.timedevents/) file. It told me to add a zope clock-server triggering the events, which i did according to the code snippet on the page.

```
[instance]
 ...
zope-conf-additional =
<clock-server>
    method /mysite/@@tick
    period 90
    user clockserver-user
    password password
    host localhost
</clock-server>
```

I changed `mysite` to my Plone URL.
The clock-server seems to work, as I got HTTP calls for the /mysite/@@tick page every 90 seconds, resulting in 404 errors, but nothing is triggered from collective.timedevents. Did I miss something or get something wrong from the documentation? Should this work?

Btw: I registered the handler from collective.autopublish for the ITickEvent.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to answer your question directly but I can provide a much more simpler solution for your problem.

As I see, what you want to achieve is, that expired content is no longer visible for the public.

Check this small addon https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.protectinactive `ftw.protectinactive`.

It automatically protects expired, or inactive content.

You in your case you may automatically set a expiration date on the content and it will be hidden to the public as soon as it reaches the date.

Comment: Pretty smart: Not working around the problem with clocks/crons and the shown UI-message is even modifiable via the web-UI. A core-candidate for solving an ever-since user-irritation, IMHO. Thx for sharing!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It does not solve the initial problem, but helps me a lot achieving what I want. it almost perfectly does what I need

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal that you get a 404 error when calling `/mysite/@@tick`. You should get a 200 code.

In fact, I had the problem myself and this is due to an error in the last releases of the package : a file (`configure.zcml`) is missing, preventing the "tick" view to work.

See the issue here : https://github.com/collective/collective.timedevents/issues/3

If you use `collective.autopublishing` 0.3, it is working. The package is broken since release 1.0.